# How to estimate the logical error rate function of different code distance parameters?

Tags: error-correction, surface-code

I know that if we have physical qubits in a grid of square shape with the same code distance of $X$ and $Z$, $d_X=d_Z=d$, then given physical qubit error rate $p$, we have logical estimate $$p_L\sim A\bigg(\frac{p}{p_{th}}\bigg)^{\frac{d}{2}}\,.$$

But what if we make the problem more complicated, such that $d_X \ne d_Z \ne d_T$, where $d_X$ is the code distance of logical $X$ operator, $d_Z$ is the code distance of logical $Z$ operator, and $d_T$ is the number of repeated measurement(code distance of temporal operator), then how can we evaluate the logical error rate under this situation?